# get child nodes having large data from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get child of node using addValueEventListener(). when books data is few, it works properly but when books count is more than 30000 it gives error as "java.lang.RuntimeException: Firebase Database encountered an OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path)."

Firebase data structre is as

```
booksData
    123 (book id)
        bookname : ""
        writer   : ""
        price    : ""
        category : ""
        publicher : ""
        ...
    456 (book id)
        bookname : ""
        writer   : ""
        price    : ""
        category : ""
        publicher : ""
        ...
    .... and so on. having vast data
```

(Data structure & name is changed just for sample)

I tried in android as

```
userIDRef1.child("booksData").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.e(TAG, "in get booksData");

            ArrayList<BooksWrapper> booksList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                BooksWrapper vtw = postSnapshot.getValue(BooksWrapper.class);
                booksList.add(vtw);
            }

            userIDRef1.child("booksData").removeEventListener(this);
            Log.e(TAG, "daybooks data size is : "+booksList.size());
            if (booksList.size() >0){
                db.addBookData(booksList);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

is there any way to get data in chunks as first 1000 books then next 1000 & so on...? Any solution please...

Comment: i think the error itself self explanatory. `you may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path)`

Comment: Use [Filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) to get data from firebase database

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.